# How to efficiently display a large number of moving points

Tags: performance, opengl, graphics

I have a large array of points, which updates dynamically. For the most part, only certain (relatively small) parts of the array get updated. The goal of my program is to build and display a picture using these points.

If I build a picture directly from the points it would be 8192 x 8192 pixels in size. I believe an optimization would be to reduce the array in size. My application has two screen areas (the one is a magnification/zooming in of the other). Additionally I will need to pan this picture in either of screen areas.

My approach for optimization is as follows.

1. Take a source array of points and reduce it with scaling factor for the first screen area
2. Same for the second area, but with larger scaling factor
3. Render there two arrays in two FBOs
4. Using FBOs as a textures (to provide ability to pan a picture)
5. When updating a picture I re-render only changed area.

Suggest ways to speed this up as my current implementation runs extremely slow.

Comment: if you have 8192x8192 = 67Mio points with two components each, this would be roughly 500mb of data. Ok thats not small. A bit more info is needed here. How do you reduce your points? how many are left for rendering? how often does one of theses 'small parts' of points change? can the parts be grouped? how often do these zoom factors change?

Comment: @Dirk Update is performed few times in second. The number of points left after reducing depending on screen size and scale factor, and thus varies. Zooming factor controlled by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will hardly be able to optimize this a lot if you don't have the hardware to run it at an adequate rate. Even if you render in different threads to FBOs and then compose the result, your bottleneck is likely to remain. 67 million data points is nothing to sneeze at, even for modern GPUs.

Try not to update unnecessarily, update only what changes, render only what's updated and visible, try to minimize the size of your components, e.g. use a shorter data type if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. It's actually seems like nothing to be done here for optimization :(